# SQL query for records that are substrings of input

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Consider a users table that has a column called name which has the following three rows.

- Alice
- Bob
- Carl

I would like to construct a query that returns records in which the name is a substring of the input. For example, if I query for Alice Jackson, I want Alice. If I search for Bobby, I want Bob. But if I search for Car, I want no matches. Sort of a reversed `LIKE`.

Can this be done? And can it be done using ActiveRecord syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like (*SQL Server syntax*):

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE 'your query' + ' ' LIKE name + ' %';
```

The following will find Alice:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE 'Alice Jackson' + ' ' LIKE name + ' %';

SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE 'Alice' + ' ' LIKE name + ' %';
```

The following will not find Alice:

```
 SELECT name
 FROM users
 WHERE 'Ali' + ' ' LIKE name + ' %';
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer was much simpler than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the syntax for SQLite to do this.

```
User.where("? LIKE name || '%'", query)
```

The double pipes are apparently neccesary for concatenation in SQLite. However, as plalx illustrates, different SQL servers speak different dialects, which makes my application database dependent with this query. Since the final query will contain additional clauses limiting the potential subset for this inverse `LIKE` to less than 10 records in most cases, I will be pulling those records and performing the matching at application level instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveRecord `IN` expression:

```
Client.where(:name => query.split(" "))
```

This code will generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.name IN ['Alice', 'Jackson']);
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer. Splitting on spaces and doing an IN is not sufficient. Bobby has to return Bob.